# Download XMLTYPE data as XML file on Oracle Apex page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, xmltype, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

My view return XMLTYPE, DATA column contains xml documents.

[image]

Is it possible on oracle apex page on button click, on page load or other way download this as eg. **TEST.XML** file

When load query in classic report and set Atributes > Apperancees > Template type : Predefineon page load documents downloads but after open xml file
get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEW>
<ROW ROWNUM="1">
  <Data>[SYS.XMLTYPE]</Data>
</ROW>
</NEW>
```

**This is not good!**

Comment: you can use interactive report and check the following link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex-tips-file-download-from-a-button-or-link

Comment: @cengizsevimli Tnx for answer, is blob content in your link example my data column? Also I don't have mime type.